# Angular - Value change of object not registering through change detection

Tags: angular, interface, ngfor, angular-changedetection, ngoninit

i'm relatively new to learning Angular and have followed some instructions from a PluralSight demo on setting up a basic service, component and HTML page.

When I run my service and debug, I can see that the service is successful in retrieving the data I need. However, part of the HTML doesn't seem to go through change detection. The date attribute I display does this successfully, however my array just gets ignored.

I've tried explicitly creating a separate array and assigning to a different variable, which also didn't work. Is there something around the ngModel and change detection I am missing?

Service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RankingService {
  private rankingUrl = 'https://localhost:44381/api/Ranking'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getRanking(): Observable<IRanking> {
    return this.http.get<IRanking>(this.rankingUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
  {{'Last Updated: ' + ranking?.startDateTime}}
</div>
<table class='table' *ngIf='ranking'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let position of ranking.rankpositions?.slice(0,30)'>
      <td>
        {{ position.Rank }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Component:

```
export class RankingListComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage = '';
  ranking: IRanking;

  constructor(private rankingService: RankingService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rankingService.getRanking().subscribe({
      next: ranking => {
        this.ranking = ranking;
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }

}
```

IRanking is an interface, with an array of rankPositions (Which represents another Interface).

As an output I get this (I've removed some HTML elements, to make the code segment smaller):

[image]

In the console, I clearly have the rankpositions array populated:
[image]

Comment: Please try `this.ranking = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ranking))`.

Comment: Tried, but no joy. From watching this.ranking in debug mode, it gets mapped without any issues.

Comment: Instead of subscribing in the component, try to use `async` pipe. That should most probably solve the issue. Looks like the references aren't updated.

Comment: Could you share the console log, code appears to be okay, and from the Last Updated value, it seems to be working. The problem might be the line `let position of ranking.rankpositions`.

Comment: The only console error is: sockjs.js:1684 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:44381/sockjs-node/148/mj40ffub/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `rankpositions` to `rankPositions`

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware Angular was case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

you've got a typo, so this should be closed.

but beyond that, running functions like that in template is pretty much always going to cause you change detection problems. use the `slice` pipe instead here for a quick fix:

```
<tr *ngFor='let position of ranking.rankPositions | slice:0:30'>
```

a better fix IMO would be switching to `async` pipe and using rx operators to run your slice.

a general angular best practice is to not run functions in templates, use pipes when appropriate, but generally your functions should be running in your component controller.

Comment: Thanks for the advice